# My JavaScript code with objects and methods isn't working

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I'm on JavaScript right now and a few days passed since I studied objects so I decided to try and make my own ones. The problem is that my code isn't really working. It prints me only the first objects. I'm sure that I will get good answers here because this place helped me a lot when I studied and experimented with HTML5 and CSS. Thanks a lot!

```js
var person_1st = {
  name: "Plamen",
  surname: "Dobrev",
  age: "14",
  favourite_colour: "blue"
};

document.write(person_1st.name + "<br />" + person_1st.surname + "<br />" + person_1st.age + "<br />" + person_1st.favourite_colour);



function person_2nd(name, surname, age, favourite_colour) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.age = age;
  this.favourite_colour = favourite_colour;
  this.new_favourite_colour = function(favourite_colour) {
    this.favourite_color = favourite_colour;
  };
};

var person_2nd_Plamen = new person_2nd("Plamen", "Dobrev", 14, "blue");
person_2nd_Plamen.new_favourite_color("red");
document.write(person_2nd_Plamen.name + "<br />" + person_2nd_Plamen.surname + "<br />" + person_2nd_Plamen.age + "<br />" + person_2nd_Plamen.favourite_colour);




function person_3rd(name, surname, age, favourite_colour) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.age = function(age) {
    this.age = age;
  };
  this.favourite_colour = favourite_colour;
};

var person_3rd_Plamen = new person_3rd("Plamen", "Dobrev", 14, "blue");
person_3rd_Plamen.age(15);
document.write(person_3rd_Plamen.name + "<br />" + person_3rd_Plamen.surname + "<br />" + person_3rd_Plamen.age + "<br />" + person_3rd_Plamen.favourite_colour);



function person_4th(name, surname, age, favourite_colour) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.age = new_age;
  this.favourite_colour = favourite_colour;
};

function new_age() {
  return 15;
};

var person_4th_Plamen = new person_4th("Plamen", "Dobrev", 14, "blue");
document.write(person_4th_Plamen.name + "<br />" + person_4th_Plamen.surname + "<br />" + person_4th_Plamen.age + "<br />" + person_4th_Plamen.favourite_colour);
```

Comment: Hey @PlamenDobrev glad you're taking an interest in JavaScript! It looks like there might be some console errors. Specifically here's one I saw: `Uncaught TypeError: person_2nd_Plamen.new_favourite_color is not a function`. If you're having trouble figuring out why that is let us know but this would be a good starting point

Comment: You have a typo: `person_2nd_Plamen.new_favourite_color` is missing the `u` in `colour`.

Comment: You should pick either American or British spelling of `color` and use it consistently everywhere.

Comment: Thank you both for the fast and good responses! The reason I probably wrote that word different on some places is because I don't speak English natively, I'll try to be more careful next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that you're interested in learning Javascript! 
As @aug mentioned in the comments, the browser-console is a great tool to figure out whats going wrong. In this case you are getting a type error: `Uncaught TypeError: person_2nd_Plamen.new_favourite_color is not a function`

In this case you had spelled `color` differently in different places.
Some times you spelled it `color` but other times `colour`.

```js
function person_2nd(name, surname, age, favourite_colour) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.age = age;
  this.favourite_colour = favourite_colour;
  this.new_favourite_colour = function(favourite_colour) {
    this.favourite_colour = favourite_colour;
  }
};

var person_2nd_Plamen = new person_2nd("Plamen", "Dobrev", 14, "blue");
person_2nd_Plamen.new_favourite_colour("red");
document.write(
  person_2nd_Plamen.name + "<br />" + 
  person_2nd_Plamen.surname + "<br />" + 
  person_2nd_Plamen.age + "<br />" + 
  person_2nd_Plamen.favourite_colour
);
console.log(person_2nd_Plamen);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and helpful response and advice. I don't speak English natively, so that's probably why I did this mistake. I'll try to be more careful next time, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PlamenDobrev No problem at all. If you feel that my answer solved your problem, then feel free to click on the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: I did, it's well deserved!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for understanding:

```
function Person() {
  this.name;
  this.surname;
  this.age;
  this.favourite_colour;
  this.assign = function(n, s, a, fc) {
    this.name = n;
    this.surname = s;
    this.age = a;
    this.favourite_colour = fc;
  }
}
var p = new Person(); // create object
p.assign("Plamen", "Dobrev", "18", "blue")
alert(p.name);

var p = [];
p.push(new Person());
p[0].assign("Plamen", "Dobrev", "18", "blue"); // first index
alert(p[0].age); // get age of first index for example
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I still can't seem to understand the last part of it, hopefully I will be able to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Plamen. Glad you're taking an interest in web development and JavaScript, hope you learn a lot.

As pointed out by a few members you mis-spelled the word `color - hit F12 on your browser to open the console and you'll get useful hints when there's an error. You can also write data directly to the console from your JavaScript code:

```
console.log("Hi, Plamen!");
```

There's some really cool things we can do in JavaScript, your code is great but we could tidy it up and make it cooler. The great thing about our object function is that we really only need to have one of them. We can use it to create multiple instances of the object, you could have a single `person` function, like this:

```
function person(name, surname, age, favourite_color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.favourite_color = favourite_color;
}
```

And use it to create lot's of people, every person you create from this object function will inherit the properties and methods of the object function.

```
person_1 = new person("My name", "My surname", 38, "blue");
person_2 = new person("Your name", "Your surname", 123, "magenta");
person_3 = new person("Someone", "else", 4321, "purple");

document.write("Person 1 name: " + person_1.name + " " + person_1.surname);
document.write("Person 2 name: " + person_2.name + " " + person_2.surname);
document.write("Person 3 name: " + person_3.name + " " + person_3.surname);

// Or, view output in console

console.log("Person 1 name: " + person_1.name + " " + person_1.surname);
console.log("Person 2 name: " + person_2.name + " " + person_2.surname);
console.log("Person 3 name: " + person_3.name + " " + person_3.surname);
```

Think of the function as a sort of template that can be used to create many instances of the object. Your instances can inherit methods as well as properties:

```
function person(name, surname, age, favourite_color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.favourite_color = favourite_color;

    this.changeFavouriteColor = function(color) {
        this.favourite_color = color;
    };

    this.changeAge = function(age) {
        this.age = age;
    };
};

person_1 = new person("me", "misturr", 20, "orange");
person_2 = new person("him", "surrr", 50, "yellow");

person_1.changeAge(21);
person_2.changeFavouriteColor("green");

console.log(`${person_1.name} is ${person_1.age} years old`);
console.log(`${person_2.name}'s favourite color is ${person_2.favourite_color}`);
```

JavaScript is pretty cool, hope you have fun and learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the great and helpful advices! Really appreciate the time you spend on writing them, along with the codes, I understood anything.